# I can’t mine or place blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I was playing Minecraft and And I fell in   was trying to get out But I got anxious and started pressing keys and now I can’t mine or place blocks or fight mobs in survival mode in Minecraft

Comment: Is this exclusively a minecraft problem? Because i know the non-function version of F12 disables the keyboard on some keyboards (at least on mine)

Comment: Maybe you unbinded your mouse on accident.

Comment: Are you still able to interact with menus in the game?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you probaly can't place or mine blocks is either because you're in **adventure mode**, or you're **lagging** *horribly*

Comment: OP stated that he is unable to attack mobs and that he was in survival, so it is very unlikely they're in adventure mode. Having terrible lag makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably having lag. Make sure your keybindings are working, and restart Minecraft and your computer.